# How do I have spaces in a MSBuild WebProjectOutputDir?

Tags: msbuild, directory-structure, path-finding

I am trying to call MSBuild from a command line.  Everything was working fine when I was using a path that had no spaces, but now I have a path that has spaces and the command is failing.

Command (works):

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe" 
/t:Rebuild "C:\Projects\myProject.csproj" 
/p:OutDir=c:\temp\deploy\funAndGames\Deployment\bin\ 
/p:WebProjectOutputDir=c:\temp\deploy\funAndGames\Deployment\ 
/p:Configuration=Release
```

I then added quotes and changed OutDir to OutPath (doesn't work):

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe" 
/t:Rebuild "C:\Projects\myProject.csproj" 
/p:OutPath="c:\temp\deploy\funAndGames\Deployment\bin\" 
/p:WebProjectOutputDir="c:\temp\deploy\funAndGames\Deployment\" 
/p:Configuration=Release
```

What I am aiming for is something like this (doesn't work):

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe" 
/t:Rebuild "C:\Projects\myProject.csproj" 
/p:OutPath="c:\temp\deploy\fun and games\Deployment\bin\" 
/p:WebProjectOutputDir="c:\temp\deploy\fun and games\Deployment\" 
/p:Configuration=Release
```

Any help on the syntax around OutDir/OutPath and WebProjectOutputDir with spaces?  Is it possible?  If it isn't does anyone know what the reason is (due to some Url's not having spaces type thing?)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just found this out an answer to this old question.
To handle spaces, you should use the escape character \ on all folders. Basically

```
/p:OutPath="c:\temp\deploy\fun and games\Deployment\bin\"
```

should be

```
/p:OutPath="c:\\temp\\deploy\\fun and games\\Deployment\\bin\\"
```

and magically it works!

Comment: Excellent! Looks like MSBuild has some funky custom way to interpret the command line. Thanks for posting your result.

Comment: So, how do you do this when you are using the macros like $(ProjectDir)?

Comment: @Mateo you can use the following: `/p:ProjectDir=&quot;$(ProjectDir.Replace('\','\\'))&quot;`

Answer (score 5):

Try add `&quot;`
ex:

```
/p:OutPath="&quot;c:\temp\deploy\fun and games\Deployment\bin\&quot;"
```

Comment: You can format as code by using `ctrl+k`, or the `{}` Button above the editor window.

Answer (score 4):

Msbuild also seems to work with spaces in the OutDir if you switch \ to /, while using quotes:

```
/p:OutDir="c:/temp/deploy/fun and games/out/"
/p:WebProjectOutputDir="c:/temp/deploy/fun and games/Deployment/"
```

Comment: Works with `/p:AspnetMergePath="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v8.0A/bin/NETFX 4.0 Tools/"` too, I just found out. Backslashes failed.

Answer (score 2):

For me the working solution is:

/p:SQLCMD="\"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE\""

In other words: Putting all the string into quotes (the external quotes aren't passed as value to MSBuild).

The value inside MSBuild for this property is: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE" (with the quotes).

Answer (score 1):

```
> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe"
> /t:Rebuild
> "C:\Projects\myProject.csproj" 
/p:OutPath="c:\temp\deploy\funAndGames\Deployment\bin\"
----------------------------------------
/p:WebProjectOutputDir="c:\temp\deploy\fun and games\Deployment\"
----------------------------------------

> /p:Configuration=Release
```

Try this.

Also try via VSStudio GUI. Then copy the settings & try with MS Build.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple parameters in a switch you can't really 'avoid' the problem by fixing the path. What you can do is put your parameters of the switch between " some_parameters1 some_parameters2 ".

Something like:

```
<Exec Command="SomeCommand /useMultipleParameterSwitch=&quot;value1:blabla1 | value2:blabla2&quot;"/>
```

Of course a lot depends of the syntax of the switches but that works for me and my team.

Comment: <Exec Command="$(SomeCommand)  /multipleSwitch=&quot;someRule:someValue | someRule2:someValue2&quot;" />
That should have been in "Something like" above.

Answer (score 0):

To do this when using a .proj file and your path is included in properties like $(DeployFolder) and $(NuGetExe), you can use "&quot;" like this:

```xml
<Exec Command="&quot;$(NuGetExe)&quot; pack -OutputDirectory &quot;$(DeployFolder)&quot;" />
```